# is there a difference between web app architecture and web app architectural design

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture, microservices, soa

I'm a bit confused about these terms. is there any difference or they are the same and what is the difference between SOA(service-oriented architecture), MVC, and Microservices?

Answer (score 0):

SOA and microserves is a way to design a system (with multiple components):

> SOA, or service-oriented architecture, defines a way to make software components reusable via service interfaces. These interfaces utilize common communication standards in such a way that they can be rapidly incorporated into new applications without having to perform deep integration each time.[1](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/soa)

> Like SOA, microservices architectures are made up of loosely coupled, reusable, and specialized components. However, rather than being adopted enterprise-wide, microservices are typically used to build individual applications in a way that makes them more agile, scalable, and resilient.[2](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/soa-vs-microservices)

Model view controller (MVC) is a way implement a given component of a system where you separate the model (business logic & data), view and controller (presentation / ui).

Comment: In MVC, the model includes the data and the business logic. The view and controller are both presentation artifacts.

Comment: The _application logic_ does not reside in the controllers, but in the _application services_, which are part of the [service layer](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html). The controllers just delegate the request data to them. MVC [ensures the separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) of the busines logic (the "M" in "MVC") from the presentation logic (the "V" & the "C" in "MVC").

Comment: Tweaked the answer based on your input.  The service layer page you linked appears to cover something different than MVC though.

Answer (score 0):

SOA and microservices are two types of software architectures. As such, they're only vaguely defined, with each architect having his or her own opinion on exactly what it means. There's no standards body that decides whether or not a particular software architecture falls into one bucket or the other.

Microservices may be service-oriented, so while these two terms don't mean exactly the same, there could be significant overlap in practice.

Contrary to these two styles of architecture, Model View Controller (MVC) is a *design pattern*, which is a more specific kind of description. Where architectural styles attempt to describe how large-scale components of a system interact, a design pattern describes how a small piece of source code is organised.

Design patterns tend to be more specifically described, which can make it a little easier to determine whether a particular piece of code is an example of a pattern or not. Even so, a design pattern name can undergo significant semantic drift, so that modern interpretations of a pattern may be unrecognisable compared to the original definition. The [Repository pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) is perhaps the most striking example, but MVC may be a close second. It seems to me that each application framework that calls itself an 'MVC framework' has its own take on just what MVC means. There seems to be little commonality between different interpretations.

Comment: thank you very much. but I feel like I still need some research. 
I'm working on my thesis on building a web app and in the design face, I have to cover the following: architectural design, program design, UI design, and database design. and I wasn't sure what was meant by architectural design because my supervisor told me to do a search on SOA and whenever I was googling "web app architecture types" I was getting MVC and the others, not the SOA and this has made a big confusion to me.